# @aws-sdk\credential-provider-node\dist-cjs\defaultProvider.js:13 CredentialsProviderError("Could not load credentials from any providers", false);

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-cognito, aws-appsync

On my *`server/index.js`* file I am trying to access *`aws-appsync`* queries as shown in [THIS](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/graphqlapi/graphql-from-nodejs/q/platform/js/#iam-authorization) documentation of **AWS GraphQL from NodeJS**. What I am looking for is to access my prior created aws-appsync service to make a **GQL query** and get response accordingly. My *Appsync* access is also related to `aws-cognito` **IAM** user on schema. So I was trying to access appsync service by using `aws-cognito` **IAM** to get the data from the service itself. but getting error of

```
E:\myProjectName\node_modules\@aws-sdk\credential-provider-node\dist-cjs\defaultProvider.js:13
throw new property_provider_1.CredentialsProviderError("Could not load credentials from any providers", false);
      ^     CredentialsProviderError: Could not load credentials from any providers
at E:\myProjectName\node_modules\@aws-sdk\credential-provider-node\dist-cjs\defaultProvider.js:13:11
at E:\myProjectName\node_modules\@aws-sdk\credential-provider-node\node_modules\@aws-sdk\property-provider\dist-cjs\chain.js:11:28 
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async coalesceProvider (E:\myProjectName\node_modules\@aws-sdk\credential-provider-node\node_modules\@aws-sdk\property-provider\dist-cjs\memoize.js:14:24)
at async SignatureV4.credentialProvider (E:\myProjectName\node_modules\@aws-sdk\credential-provider-node\node_modules\@aws-sdk\property-provider\dist-cjs\memoize.js:33:24)
at async SignatureV4.signRequest (E:\myProjectName\node_modules\@aws-sdk\signature-v4\dist-cjs\SignatureV4.js:86:29)    at async handler (file:///E:/myProjectName/server/index.js:86:20) { tryNextLink: false }
```

Let me share my Code

---

```
import express from 'express';
const app = express();
import path from 'path';
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
import fs from 'fs';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import crypto from '@aws-crypto/sha256-js';
import { defaultProvider } from '@aws-sdk/credential-provider-node';
import { SignatureV4 } from '@aws-sdk/signature-v4';
import { HttpRequest } from '@aws-sdk/protocol-http';
import { default as fetch, Request } from 'node-fetch';

const { Sha256 } = crypto;
const GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT = 'https://myawsendpoint.amazonaws.com/graphql'
const AWS_REGION = 'us-east-1'
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

app.use(express.static(
path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build')
));

app.listen(PORT, (error) => {
    if (error) {
        return console.log('Error during app startup', error);
    }
    console.log("listening on " + PORT + "...");
});

const indexPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build', 'index.html');

const query = `query MyQuery {
  listCountrys {
    items {
      countryName
    }
  }
}

const handler = async (event) => {
console.log(`EVENT: ${JSON.stringify(event)}`);

const endpoint = new URL(GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT);
console.log("endpoint", endpoint)

const signer = new SignatureV4({
    credentials: defaultProvider({ timeout: 2000, maxRetries: 2 }),
    region: AWS_REGION,
    service: 'appsync',
    sha256: Sha256
});

const requestToBeSigned = new HttpRequest({
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        host: endpoint.host
    },
    hostname: endpoint.host,
    body: JSON.stringify({ query }),
    path: endpoint.pathname
});

console.log("=== requestToBeSigned", requestToBeSigned)

const signed = await signer.sign(requestToBeSigned);
const request = new Request(endpoint, signed);

let statusCode = 200;
let body;
let response;

try {
    response = await fetch(request);
    body = await response.json();
    console.log("=== body response", body)
    if (body.errors)
        statusCode = 400;
} catch (error) {
    console.log("=== body response error", error)
    statusCode = 500;
    body = {
        errors: [
            {
                message: error.message
            }
        ]
    };
}

return {
    statusCode,
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
};

}

app.get('^/public/posts/:id', (req, res, next) => {
        handler()
    });
});
```

Schema :

```
@aws_iam
@aws_cognito_user_pools
    listCountrys(filter: ModelCountryFilterInput, limit: Int, nextToken: String): ModelCountryConnection
```

I don't know what I missed actually. I am providing exactly what was told on the documentation. Can anyone enlighten me please? Thanks in advance.

---

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with Nodemailer and AWS SES.

Anyone who is being redirected to this SO Question like I was, this work around might help.

```
import * as AWS from "aws-sdk";
import * as nodemailer from "nodemailer";

export const EmailService = async () => {
    AWS.config.update({
        accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
    });

    const ses = new AWS.SES({ apiVersion: "****-**-**" });

    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        SES: ses,
    });

    try {
        const response = await transporter.sendMail({
            from: process.env.ADMIN_EMAIL,
            to: userEmail,
            subject: "Test Mail",
            html: `
                <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
                <html>
                    <head>
                        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <div style="padding:20px;">
                            <div style="max-width: 500px;">
                                <h2>Test Mail</h2>
                                <p>
                                    Hi there,<br/><br/>
                                    This is a test mail.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </body>
                </html>
            `,
        });

        if (response?.messageId) {
            return {
                status: true,
                message: response?.messageId,
            };
        } else {
            return {
                status: false,
                message: "Failed to send email",
            };
        }
    } catch (error: any) {
        return {
            status: false,
            message: error.message,
        };
    }
};
```

Here is the actual way of doing it https://nodemailer.com/transports/ses/